# Send parameters to a user-defined function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

We define a user-defined function as follows.

```
def testfun(x):
    return( x[0]*a+x[1]*b)
```

Call the function:

```
sol =  optimize.root(testfun, [0, 0], method = 'lm')
```

How can we pass `a` and `b` when calling the function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this problem specifically, `optimize.root` has an `args` input which accepts a tuple of values to pass as additional inputs to your objective function:

```
def testfun(x, a, b):
    return ([x[0] * a + x[1] * b])

# Specify values for a and b
a = 1
b = 2

sol = optimize.root(testfun, [0, 0], method='lm', args=(a, b))
```

More generally, you can use a lambda function to provide additional inputs to any function

```
# Create a lambda function which passes the input provided by optimize.root and adds 
# two more inputs: a and b
func = lambda x: testfun(x, a, b)

# Pass this lambda function to optimize.root
sol = optimize.root(func, [0, 0], method='lm')
```

Comment: Okay. Got the point. However, even if I don't send the values a, b separately in the function definition, they were able to take the values ? Is it because they are global variables by default ?

Comment: @learner123 You *could* use global variables but passing them explicitly is preferred.

Comment: Okay.  I make the habit of passing them explicitly.

Comment: @learner123 See the update using the `args` input to `optimize.root`

Comment: Thanks for extending your answer.

so, a= 2, b =3

`optimize.root(testfun, [0, 0], method='lm', args=(a, b))`

a = 4, b = 5

`optimize.root(testfun, [0, 0], method='lm', args=(a, b))`

Is it the use of `args` in `optimize.root` function ? 

Just curious, what is the need of `args` option in `root` function. By default they are already global.

Comment: @learner123 Yes they are global in the snippet that I've in shown but this is not generally the case. Your objective function may actually live within a different scope completely. It's also good practice to pass values to your objective function explicitly so someone debugging your code can easily determine where the values came from.